# Add attributes to immutable type subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, immutability

I have been trying to emulate a binary register of arbitrary length that would be manipulated like a Python `int` , but would be initialized with a fixed length and would have special overflow/underflow behavior. (ie you could add it to other `int`s, and get a `Register` of the same length in return)

Reading a bit about it, it seems it is recommended to subclass `int`, and I have been reading [this](https://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subclass-int.html) on immutable type subclassing; but I can't wrap my head around how I would add an attribute to that.

It seems to me this should be possible, since I am an only trying to add static behavior. But code of the form :

```
def __new__(S, size, *args, **kwargs)
    r = super(Register, S).__new__(S, 0)
    r.maxVal = 2**size
    return r
```

seems nonsensical, since `r` is immutable. I don't even know where I would put that `maxVal`. It does execute without errors (calling `r = Register.__new__(Register, 16) ; print(r)` prints `0`, in spite of me overloading `__repr__`), but still, I have no idea of what I'm doing here.

Hence my asking for help. Is this behavior possible, desirable? Is this approach correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The same parameters are used interfacing `__new__()` and `__init__()`. This way, one can...

- create a new instance in `__new__()`, using `super()` without the additional argument, and
- add an attribute in `__init__()`, based on the additional argument.

```
    class Register(int):

      def __new__(cls, size, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

      def __init__(self, size, *args, **kwargs):
        self.maxVal = 2**size
```